# How can one get the appwidget's own ID?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, android-appwidget

I am trying to debug a problem where my widget becomes invalid and a new one fills in.  This only happens once at the beginning of time and then it remains the second widget forever.  So, I want to put code in to narrow down the point in time when it happens.  What I would like to do it something like this:

```
e.g., (not real code) Log.d(TAG, "myWidgetId=" + this.getMyWidgetId());
```

Then I would get a list of all the enabled IDs and see if I am in the list.  I cannot find a method, member, attribute, etc. that would give me my id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done.  The AppWidgetProvider's ID is implicitly handled and can change, therefore, the best one can do is to ask the AppWidgetManager to generate a list of the widgets for a particular component, invoke them, then respond to the service request using the provided ID.

Comment: HOw do we do that? I mean any sample code, how to get list of widget ids using AppWidgetManager? Please help.

Comment: In which cases does the id change? I assume that only upon creation of new AppWidgets, no?